# Lagrange Multipliers for minimizing costs

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

A closed rectangular box with a volume of $16000$ $\text{cm}^3$ is made from two kinds of materials. The top and bottom are made of material costing $\$0.10$ per centimetre squared and the sides from material costing $\$0.05$ per centimetre squared. Find the dimensions of the box so that the cost of materials is minimized.

I have $V(x,y,z)=16000$ and Cost $C(x)=0.2xy+0.1zx+0.1zy$

Using
$F(x,y,z,\lambda)=0.2xy+0.1zx+0.1zy+\lambda(xyz-16000)$
We get the system:

$F_x= 0.2y+0.1z+\lambda(yz) = 0$

$F_y= 0.2x+0.1z+\lambda(xz) = 0$

$F_z=0.1y+0.1x+\lambda(xy) = 0$

$F_\lambda=xyz-16000 = 0$

Taking first and second and then second and third equations,

I get $x=y$

$y=20$

$2y=z = 40$

$\lambda=-4.005$

I just want to make sure I did the process correctly, and that the process of maximizing and minimizing are the same, but just depend on the value of $\lambda$.

thank you and any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: That's fine but first - second also gives a factor $0.2+Lz$. The process finds a turning point but does not tell you if it is a max or a min. A physical argument (min often must be 0) can help you decide if you have more than one choice

Comment: Yes, explain how you got $x=y$ exactly?

Comment: BTW the value of $\lambda$ is irrelevant, you don't have to give it.

Comment: (-0.2y-0.1z)/yz = (-0.2x-0.1z)/xz , solving both sides leads to y=x